# Cannot retrieve user_location from facebook connect

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using an old SDK connection that works fine

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js"></script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="false" scope="email,user_birthday,user_location" size="medium">Facebook
</fb:login-button>

FB.api('/me?', 
{ fields: 'name, email, gender,first_name,last_name,birthday,location' }, 
     function(response) { 
       console.log(response);
});
```

that works fine.

When I try to add fields such as: **user_location, user_birthday**

response gives: error

Answer (score 1):

Please see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading

for an overview which fields are available with the `User` object. The fields you're apparantly interested in are `location` and `birthday`.

```
FB.api('/me', 
    { fields: 'name, email,gender,first_name,last_name,location,birthday' },     
    function(response) { 
       console.log(response);
    }
);
```

Comment: gender is now added ! But No location neither borthday !

Comment: Are you sure your Access Token really contains the permissions?

Comment: what is the access token and where can I find it ?

Comment: Now I use: <fb:login-button show-faces="false" scope="email,user_birthday,user_location" size="medium">Facebook
</fb:login-button>

FB.api('/me?', 
{ fields: 'name, email, gender,first_name,last_name,birthday,location' }, 
     function(response) { 
       console.log(response);
});
but birthday and location are still absent

Comment: If you don't know what an Access Token is please read the docs before posting these questions. Furthermore, you need to test this with an admin/Tester/Developer of your app if it didn't pass Login Review yet.

Comment: Hi Tobi, It looks like problem comes from new changes in FB: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review : to access these data you need to submit your application for review !

Comment: That's what I wrote in my last comment